# Can I setup Apache Storm multi-node cluster in VMWare?

Tags: vmware, apache-storm

I do not have machines to setup my cluster. Is there any way storm multi-node cluster can be setup and run successfully in single machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing preventing you from running multiple Storm nodes in virtual machines. Just make sure the VMs can reach each other on the ports used by Storm and Zookeeper (see the documentation at https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html).

Unless you're testing that your application works when running on multiple nodes, I'm not sure why you'd want to run many nodes on one machine? Storm is distributed to avoid a single point of failure, balance load and scale horizontally, none of which would apply to one machine running many nodes.